# Importing javax package in Java without an IDE

Tags: java, swing, java-7

I'm developing a project in [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) using [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29), and I need to use some classes from the javax package. What should I install and configure to be able to import any of them?

I already installed the [JDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) 7 and also put it as my default using update-alternative command.

For example, when I compile a class (for example one called GUI) that uses the javax package, the compiler displays:

```
> javac GUI.java
GUI.java:1: error: package javax does not exists
import javax.swing;
^
1 error
```

I think it is related to the $CLASSPATH environment variable, but I'm not sure how to tell the compiler where the package is (since it is inside the JDK 7).

Comment: import a class or package, e.g. `import javax.swing.*;`

Comment: I think the bigger question here is why you are you having to write code using vim! A `ctrl+shift+o` would have fixed your compile issue in Eclipse.

Comment: I'm doing that. The thing is javac is not recognizing the package even I installed the JDK 7 and set it to default.

Comment: @Jcao02 no you are not doing that, your import is wrong.

Comment: @Jcao02 you are trying to import the class named `swing` from the package `javax` which is very different from "import javax.swing.*;

Comment: It doesn't matter if I want to use an IDE or not, the doubt is how to get javac read the package by itself.

Comment: @Jcao02 Once the syntax is correct the JDK will find the correct classes/packages in its own JAR files

Comment: Oh, yes I was doing it wrong, didn't notice it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of trying to import `javax.swing`, which does not actually specify anything specific, you should import `javax.swing.*`. This imports everything in the `javax.swing` package.

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

You can also import specific swing components and utilities:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
```

See The Java Tutorials page on [Using Package Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) for more information about importing package members.

Answer (score 3):

You should be importing as:

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

or else for example

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
```